# How to create Google Chart friendly JSON arrays from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, google-visualization

I think I'm close to completing the passing of MySQL data to Google Charts through JSON/AJAX. I am able to output a JSON string in the correct format but it is not outputting any SQL data. I've searched everywhere for a solution with no results. Anyone see what is missing from the code?

**JSON output**

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"projid","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"hours","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":""},{"v":0}]}]}
```

**PHP->JSON**

```
<?php
// -----> Query MySQL and parse into JSON below. <------

// write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)

require_once ("Includes/session.php");
require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php");
require_once ("Includes/connectDB.php");

$recId = null;
$projid = null;
$hours = null;

        $recId = $_GET['id'];
        $projid = $_GET['projid'];
        $hours = $_GET['hours'];
        $query = "SELECT projid, hours FROM hours WHERE id = ?";
        $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('d', $recId);
        $statement->execute();
        $results = $statement->get_result();

  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => "",'label' => 'projid', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => "",'label' => 'hours', 'type' => 'number')
);


    /* Extract the information from $result */
    while ($r = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
      $temp = array();

      // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['projid']); 

      // Values of each slice
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['hours']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
```

?>

Comment: I assume from your code that you are using PDO's for your database I/O, is that correct, or are you using another system that looks similar to PDO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code returned the correct array for Google Charts. [Google Charts - JSON Data](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example)

```
<?php 

// -----> Query MySQL and parse into JSON below. <------

require_once  ("Includes/connectDB.php");

$result = $databaseConnection->query("SELECT projid, hours FROM alloc_hours");      
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'projid', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'hours', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number')
    );
    $rows = array();
    while ($nt = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['projid'], 'f' =>NULL);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['hours'], 'f' =>NULL);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Array

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"projid","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"hours","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"8","f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"6","f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"3","f":null},{"v":"20","f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"2","f":null},{"v":"10","f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"4","f":null},{"v":"5","f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"1","f":null},{"v":"30","f":null}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
$statement->store_result();
```

with:

```
$results = $statement->get_result();
```

and replace the `foreach` loop with a `while` loop:

```
while ($r = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $temp = array();

    // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['projid']);

    // Values of the each slice

    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['hours']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
```

That should get the query to return results.  You don't need the lines:

```
$statement->bind_result($projid, $hours);
$statement->fetch();
```

Comment: The updates you suggested output: `{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"projid","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"hours","type":"number"}],"rows":[]}` What would be causing the query data to not be passed to the array?

Comment: It might be due to a typo - I missed the "$" that should be in front of `$results->fetch_assoc()`.  Edited my answer above with the fix.

Comment: I did notice that the "$" was missing before testing your solution. I updated the question's code to incorporate your suggestions. Are there any further errors that cause the output to not include the SQL data? Would you suggest a different approach for passing MySQLi queries to JSON?